# "Além de também..." é gramaticamente correto?

Tags: gramática

Minha frase é "além de também ter um preço acessível." 
A frase está correta? Se eu tirar o "também", está certo?
"Além de ter também um preço acessível" é melhor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em linguagem corrente, diria que a frase está correta.

*"Além de"* significa que se está a acrescentar alguma coisa a algo dito anteriormente.

Por sua vez, *"também"* acaba por acrescentar alguma coisa. Deste ponto de vista, poderemos dizer qeu estamos perante uma redundância (ou um pleonasmo).

No entanto, penso que não esteja incorreto na sua forma, por via de um reforço de ideia (concordar com a ideia anterior) ou simplesmente com o mesmo valor d adição.
Ex: O carro é novo, além de (também) ter um preço acessível.
O carro é muito caro, além de (também) estar muito gasto.

Assim, se tirar o *também*, a frase está correta, com o mesmo valor de adição. Apenas se perde o tal reforço de repetição, cujo único *problema* que possa existir seja mesmo o pleonasmo.

Answer (score 2):

Me soa natural, especialmente quando se referindo a objetos distintos, por exemplo:

> Este carro tem um preço acessível.
>   E este outro, além de também ter um preço acessível, tem mais espaço.